# Why are LINGER=0 and SNDTIMEO=0 used for Zyre actors' PAIR sockets?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

Reviewing Pyre's (Python version of Zyre) source code, I saw the following:

```
def zcreate_pipe(ctx, hwm=1000):
    backend = zsocket.ZSocket(ctx, zmq.PAIR)
    frontend = zsocket.ZSocket(ctx, zmq.PAIR)
    # ...
    # close immediately on shutdown
    backend.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
    frontend.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)

class ZActor(object):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, ctx, actor, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.pipe, self.shim_pipe = zhelper.zcreate_pipe(ctx)
        # ...

    def run(self):
        self.shim_handler(*self.shim_args, **self.shim_kwargs)
        self.shim_pipe.set(zmq.SNDTIMEO, 0)
        self.shim_pipe.signal()
        self.shim_pipe.close()

    def destroy(self):
        # ...
        self.pipe.set(zmq.SNDTIMEO, 0)
        self.pipe.send_unicode("$TERM")
        self.pipe.wait()
        self.pipe.close()
```

Interesting to me were the uses of `LINGER=0` and `SNDTIMEO=0`.

The corresponding docs are [here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-setsockopt#toc10) and [here](http://api.zeromq.org/2-2:zmq-setsockopt#toc17):

> **ZMQ_SNDTIMEO: Maximum time before a send operation returns with EAGAIN**
>
> [rather self-explanatory]
>
> **ZMQ_LINGER: Set linger period for socket shutdown**
>
> [...] The linger period determines how long pending messages which have yet to be sent to a peer shall linger in memory after a socket is closed with zmq_close(3), and further affects the termination of the socket's context with zmq_term(3). [...]
>
> - [...]
> - The value of 0 specifies no linger period. Pending messages shall be discarded immediately when the socket is closed with zmq_close().
> - [...]

So in short, the last message in both directions may not be sent. If `send` would block, `SNDTIMEO=0` would kick in, and (presumably if there is still something in the send queue) `LINGER=0` could discard the message during `close`.

That seems like a bad idea, because if `$TERM` is discarded, the actor isn't killed, and if the `signal` is discarded, the calling thread would just block. The only way it makes sense to me is if the messages may never be discarded (because of some characteristics of `PAIR` over `inproc://` transport?), but then, why use the socket options in the first place?

What makes this code work as expected, why were the socket options used this way, and in what situation should/shouldn't I follow this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a latent bug (deadlock/hang) to me.  If the actor doesn't read messages sent to it fast enough, the queue (with size 'hwm') could be full - meaning that zmq won't send anything, and the destroy() will end up waiting on a signal expected when the actor exits - but since the actor never receives "$TERM", it can't react - and unless there's a timeout in its recv(), it may wait forever for a message as well.

[ I notice there appears to be a skeptical comment just before the wait() in the destroy() method - so you may not be the first to notice this ]

I'd handle destroy() with care - practically speaking, you could code your solution so that overflowing the queue is highly unlikely - or you could check whether the send succeeds in destroy() - and if not - either try again (with timeout) or just skip the wait().

Comment: actually - you could just test the fact that it's a bug by writing an actor that doesn't receive anything from the queue.  Keep sending messages until they fail (queue full), then call destroy() - and you should hang.

Comment: I'll try that; does the use of LINGER and SNDTIMEO make the situation better or worse in any way? Learning what to take away from this implementation is my main concern here...

Comment: The SNDTIMEO is likely there to keep destroy() from waiting if the queue is full - though the subsequent call to wait() seems like it would defeat that.  

Ditto for the LINGER setting - making that zero will cause the in-process pipe to be closed immediately even if there are pending (unread) messages in the pipe.  Likely the subsequent wait() was added to make sure that the actor received the $TERM and exited before closing the pipe (and killing the possibly unread $TERM message)